# How to change md-whiteframe value on scroll down in Material Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am new to Material Angular, and just started using it around a month ago, so this might be a simple question.  Anyway, I have a toolbar set to a white frame of 0.  When I scroll down in my md-content I would like to have the white frame value change to 2 or 4 or just another number, hence giving it a shadow.  I also would like to have it animate, not having the shadow just blink/appear.  An example of that would be the [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) website.  If you look at the picture bellow you will see a line under the toolbar.  Then the Picture under that shows that when you scroll it turns into a shadow.  [image: Google Fonts Navbar Outline]Outline above.
[image: Google Fonts Toolbar Shadow] Shadow above.

I would try to invest time in inspecting their css, js, and html, but I am actually working on a project for school, which is due next Friday, and I have to type up a bunch of content, and gather information.

I was able to make a shadow appear at the bottom of the md-content, but that was by adding a css selector with a box-shadow when I scrolled down, I just can't figure out how to change the md-whiteframe value on scroll.

I have tried to use a variable.  Like `md-whiteframe="{{ctrl.elevation}}"`
Then say something like

```
if(item.scrolltop > 0) {
this.elevation = 0;} else {
this.elevation = 4;}
```

I tried something like that in my js, but it just ended up as a mess.  This isn't a really big deal I am just trying to give my project some nice touches.  I would really appreciate any help though.  Thank you in advance.  Also I looked for questions similar to this, and didn't find any that were what I wanted, but if you find a question that answers this then please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to act on the class property of the md-whiteframe directive.
For instance:

```
<md-whiteframe class="{{ctrl.elevationClass}}">
    <span>My content</span>
</md-whiteframe>
```

On your controller:

```
if(item.scrolltop > 0) {
    this.elevationClass = 'md-whiteframe-1dp';
} else {
    this.elevationClass = 'md-whiteframe-4dp';
}
```

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/whiteframe